# React/Nextjs MediaRecording fails to stop recording using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mediarecorder

I am creating a web app that does the following:

1. Get Camera permisson
2. Start Recording after a 3 second countdown
3. Video can record when pressing a stop recording button, or it needs to stop recording
   after 15 seconds total (Adding logic for this makes the app fail)
4. once the app finishes recording it uploads to firebasestorage and then to coconut.io for encoding a watermark.

The above works great, minus the stop recording after 15 seconds.
Whenever I add the following to my startRecording function it fails:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    stopRecording();
}, 15000);
```

This is the error it gives whenever i add the timeout:

```
net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE
```

Its using the same function as when a user would press a button so im honestly not sure why it wont work.

Any help on why this is happening or ideas how i can stop the recording after 15 seconds would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Here is my full code:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import useUploadFile from "../hooks/useUploadFile";
import useStepStore from "../stores/stepStore";
import useLanguageStore from "../stores/languageStore";
import Timer from "../components/common/Timer";
import StepBanner from "../components/common/StepBanner";



const mimeType = 'video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"';

const VideoMessage: React.FC = () => {

    const setStep = useStepStore((state) => state.setStep);

    const language = useLanguageStore((state) => state.language);

    const { uploadFile, downloadURL, uploading, progress, coconutJobId } = useUploadFile();

    const [permission, setPermission] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [permissionClicked, setPermissionClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const mediaRecorder = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);

    const liveVideoFeed = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

    const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState<"inactive" | "recording">("inactive");

    const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>(null);

    const [recordedVideo, setRecordedVideo] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const [videoChunks, setVideoChunks] = useState<BlobPart[]>([]);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(0);







    const getCameraPermission = async () => {
        setRecordedVideo(null);

        if ("MediaRecorder" in window) {
            try {
                const videoConstraints = {
                    audio: false,
                    video: true,
                };
                const audioConstraints = { audio: true };

                const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(audioConstraints);
                const videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConstraints);

                setPermission(true);
                setPermissionClicked(true)

                const combinedStream = new MediaStream([
                    ...videoStream.getVideoTracks(),
                    ...audioStream.getAudioTracks(),
                ]);

                setStream(combinedStream);
                if (liveVideoFeed.current) {
                    liveVideoFeed.current.srcObject = videoStream;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                alert((err as Error).message);
            }
        } else {
            alert("The MediaRecorder API is not supported in your browser.");
        }
    };



    const handleStartRecording = () => {
        setCountdown(3);
        const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            setCountdown(prevCountdown => {
                if (prevCountdown <= 1) {
                    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
                    startRecording(); // Start recording after the countdown
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return prevCountdown - 1;
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    };


    const startRecording = async () => {
        setRecordingStatus("recording");

        if (stream) {
            const media = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType });

            mediaRecorder.current = media;

            let localVideoChunks: BlobPart[] = [];

            mediaRecorder.current.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                if (typeof event.data === "undefined") return;
                if (event.data.size === 0) return;
                localVideoChunks.push(event.data);
            };

            mediaRecorder.current.start();
            setVideoChunks(localVideoChunks);

            setTimeout(() => {
                stopRecording();
            }, 15000);
       
        }
        
    };

    const stopRecording = () => {
        setPermission(false);
        setRecordingStatus("inactive");

        if (mediaRecorder.current) {
            mediaRecorder.current.onstop = () => {
                const videoBlob = new Blob(videoChunks, { type: mimeType });
                const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

                const file = new File([videoBlob], "video.webm", {
                    type: "video/webm",
                });

                console.log("file: ", file);

                setRecordedVideo(videoUrl);
                console.log("videoUrl: ", videoUrl);
                uploadFile(videoBlob);
                console.log({ loading, downloadURL, uploading, progress, coconutJobId });

                setVideoChunks([]);
            };
            mediaRecorder.current.stop();
        }
    };





    const getVideo = async () => {
        while (true) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('/api/status', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ coconutJobId: coconutJobId })
                })

                const data = await res.json();
                console.log("data: ", data);
                if (data.job.status === "job.completed") {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setStep(4);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);

                break;
            }

            // Wait for 5 seconds before the next check
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
        }
    }

    getVideo();


    return (
        <div className="w-3/4 m-auto  flex flex-col justify-center align-center items-center">
            <StepBanner />
            <div className="w-full mb-5">
                <p className="text-left font-bold text-xl">{language === "en" ? "Record a video to send" : "Enregistrer une vidéo à envoyer"}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="indicator ">
                {/* {countdown > 0 ?  <span className="indicator-item indicator-top indicator-middle badge bg-[orange] text-xl"><Timer time={3}/></span> : ''} */}
                {/* {recordingStatus === "recording" ? <span className="indicator-item indicator-top indicator-middle badge bg-[orange] text-xl"><Timer time={15} /></span> : ""} */}

                <div className="video-player m-auto w-[300px] aspect-[4/5] bg-black relative">
                    {/* Positioning the Timer component */}
                    {countdown > 0 ? <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 mt-[-100px] z-10 text-white font-bold text-[100px]"><Timer time={3} /></div> : ""}
                    {recordingStatus === "recording" &&
                    <div className="absolute top-[35%] left-[85%] transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 mt-[-100px] z-10 text-white font-bold text-[40px] flex items-center space-x-2">
                        <div className="badge badge-primary badge-md bg-[red]"></div>
                        <Timer time={15} />
                    </div>
                    }

                    {!recordedVideo ? (
                        <video ref={liveVideoFeed} autoPlay muted loop className="live-player w-[300px] aspect-[4/5]" poster="/cards/2023/card_1.jpg"></video>
                    ) : null}

                    {recordedVideo ? (
                        <div className="recorded-player">
                            <video className="recorded aspect-[4/5] w-[300px]" src={recordedVideo} autoPlay muted loop></video>
                        </div>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="video-controls w-full mb-20">
                {!permission && !permissionClicked ? (
                    <button onClick={getCameraPermission} type="button" className="btn z-9999 w-full  bg-[#c41f3e] my-2 text-center rounded-xl h-10 align-middle text-white border-none">
                        {language === "en" ? "Allow Camera" : "Autoriser la caméra"}
                    </button>
                ) : null}
                {permission && recordingStatus === "inactive" ? (
                    <button onClick={handleStartRecording} type="button" className="btn z-9999 w-full  bg-[#c41f3e] my-2 text-center rounded-xl h-10 align-middle text-white border-none">
                        {language === "en" ? "Start Recording" : "Commencer l'enregistrement"}
                    </button>
                ) : null}
                {recordingStatus === "recording" ? (
                    <button onClick={stopRecording} type="button" className="btn z-9999 w-full  bg-[#c41f3e] my-2 text-center rounded-xl h-10 align-middle text-white border-none">
                        {language === "en" ? "Stop Recording" : "Arrêter l'enregistrement"}
                    </button>
                ) : null}
                {recordedVideo ? (
                    <button className="btn z-9999 w-full min-w-full bg-[#c41f3e] my-2 text-center rounded-xl h-10 align-middle text-white border-none" disabled><span className="loading loading-spinner loading-md"></span>
                    </button>) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VideoMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking the mimeType properly? Apparently my web app works well on my windows OS (video/webm), but when I was testing it on my Android device (chrome), it has the same error as yours (it doesn't even bother to go countdown and it gave me the error message straight away). What I did was to let it loop through an array of mimeType and then choose the one that is compatible with our device (?). After doing so, my code works well again. Hope it helps :D